# Ruby on Rails, how to disable/turn off ETag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, etag

Greetings,

How do I turn off ETag(s) in Ruby on Rails v2.3.5

When I do a direct request to to the RoR/Mongrel an ETag header is present.

TIA,

-daniel

Answer (score 26, accepted):

much easier:

```
config.middleware.delete Rack::ETag
```

Comment: Does this work for Rails 2.3 (as asked by the OP), or it's Rails-3 only?

Comment: This was potentially the most helpful answer I've seen on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Putting `response.etag = nil` in a before_filter does not work. The etag is generated just before the response is send (it's caluculated from the body so after all rendering has been done).

The proper workaround to disable etag use and generation (and so save the time spend in md5) it this monkey patch:

```
module ActionController
  class Request
    # never match any incomming etag
    def etag_matches?(etag)
      false
    end
  end

  class Response
    # fake rails that our response already has an etag set and so none is generated automatically
    def etag?
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an [`etag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Response.html#M000621) setter method on the `ActionController::Response` object, which deletes the ETag HTTP header if it's blank, so you should just be able to clear it in your controller (probably in a before filter):

```
response.etag = nil
```

Comment: yes, but I need to do it for all responses, while I could do it for each controller, that would get tedious after a while and be mistake prone. What if someone missed one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they are on by default.

My understanding is that they need to be explicitly set using stale?/fresh_when call or similar.

Comment: I checked the controller there is no conditional get code.

-daniel

Answer (score 0):

I am working in Rails 4 on WEBrick, trying to get a response to cache until it expires at a specific time each day. It looks like the auto-generated ETag is interfering with the expiration cache which is why I searched for this answer. I didn't find anything helpful here, but I did solve my problem, so I'll share.

tl;dr Set the `Last-Modified` header

But set it to what? In my situation I was trying to optimize a web service that returned the results of a process that runs at the same time every day. My response headers ended up looking like this:

```
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = "max-age=86400"
response.headers['Expires'] = getCacheTime
response.headers['Last-Modified'] = getLastModified
```

First you want to explicitly write the `Cache-Control` header to overwrite whatever the default is. I set mine to be 24 hours to coincide with the maximum of my expiration header. I set the expiration header with a function the looks something like this:

```
def getCacheTime
    now = Time.now.utc
    cacheTime = Time.utc(now.year, now.month, now.day, 22, 00, 00)
    if now > cacheTime
        cacheTime = cacheTime + (60 * 60 * 24)
    end

    cacheTime.httpdate
end
```

The *getLastModified* function returns exactly 24 hours less than the *getCacheTime* function. It seems that setting this will suppress the ETag (another validation caching header) at least in my current development environment.

Answer (score -1):

Why not add a before_filter in your application controller which sets etag to nil?

Comment: I would prefer not to have to adjust some 30+ controllers and also make sure everyone sets it right in the future. :)

Comment: If you put the before_filter in your application_controller it get run for all controllers, and if for any reason you have a controller that does need to generate etags just use skip_before_filter.